# How to choose the number of shards in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am wondering what is the best way to estimate the number of shards when you are just starting to use CH on Production?
i am currently using 3 shards 2 replicas

Answer (score 3):

Most workloads will not need more than 1 shard. Scale vertically and use replicas across machines for high availability only. A single shard can scale to PBs and hundreds of cores - query execution is highly parallel within a shard. There should be no reason to scale horizontally unless you are heavily restricted by your hardware profile and have multiple PBs. If the former, minimize your shard count. If the latter, use the largest machines cost efficiency permits.